# Vertical scroll not working inside ul tag overlay in Angular app

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to scroll through a list of items, but scroll is working only for some of the items, not all. After a certain item, the scroll stops and does not go the last item.

Here is the **Stackblitz** link.
https://angular-cym8q4.stackblitz.io/

This is for a chatlist overlay which contains list of profiles. Please refer to the following screenshot:
[image: Chatlist screenshot]

In the above screenshot, I am not able to scroll through all the profiles. Scroll if happening for only some of the profiles, it is not going to the very end of the list.

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 d-none d-lg-block col-offset-5 red coloverlay bg-custom">
            <app-chatlist></app-chatlist>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.coloverlay {
  background-color: rgba(233, 33, 33, 0.4);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-custom {
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

**chatlist.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row m-0 ">
        <div class="col p-0">

            <div class="d-flex flex-row chatlistbox ">
                <div class="m-2">
                    Chat
                </div>

                <div class="ml-auto mt-1 pr-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-minimize " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="m-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="customList">
                <ul class="list-group  overflow-auto" id="contact-list">
                    <app-chatlist-item class="list-group-item p-0 border-0" *ngFor="let el of elList" [element]="el">
                    </app-chatlist-item>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**chatlist.component.css**

```
.overflow-auto {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.customList {
  height: 93%;
}

.chatlistbox {
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 2%;
}
```

**chatlist-item.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row bg-custom item">
    <div class="p-2">
        <img src="{{element.imagePath}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap name">
            <h6 class="m-0">
                {{element.firstName}} {{element.lastName}}
            </h6>
            <span class="details">
                {{element.details}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**chatlist-item.component.css**

```
img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg-custom {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

* {
  color: #e3dcdc;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #32465a;
}
```

I am not sure what is the problem. Any help would be highly apprecitated.

Comment: If you could reproduce this in a JsFiddle, or in a StackOverflow snippet, it would be much easier for us to help

Comment: @user184994 I am sorry I am new to webdevelopment, is it possible to reproduce angular code there?

Comment: No, but you can use StackBlitz in that case

Comment: @user184994 I tried StackBlitz as well, but I suppose they don't support creating new components as far as I could figure out.

Comment: No, they do. Just click the little square with a plus to add a file

Comment: Thanks. Im not seeing any scroll bar on that though? Did you add your CSS?

Comment: @user184994 Yes, I am not sure, some css class is not getting applied. I will check again.

Comment: @user184994 Bootstrap class was not getting applied through node-module, so I directly copied the content in styles.css. You may check the url now. 
https://angular-cym8q4.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the container is taller than the page, so the scroll bar goes off the page.

To fix it, you need to set the height on some of the elements, like so:

```
.container-fluid.p-0,
.row.m-0,
.col.p-0 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Finally, you will need to change the height of `customList`. I would recommend using `calc` instead of a fixed percentage, which may not be what you want.

```
.customList {
  height: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Here is a fork of the stackblitz with the CSS fixed:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7c7dmk?file=src/app/chatlist/chatlist.component.css

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now. It works perfectly with your fix.